# Positive and negative examples in Rocchio-based recommender

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

I am exploring the usage of Rocchio-based recommenders in e-commerce and news portals and trying to wrap my head about the concept of a negative rating. Often in e-commerce or news portals there is no such thing as negative rating - the user either purchases a seen item (clicks on a seen article) or does nothing (what happens for the most of items).

Obviously, a purchase/click can be interpreted as a positive rating (e.g., *like*). But what with items that were seen, but no action has followed? Is it considered as a negative rating (e.g., *not like*)?

If I want to use a Rocchio-method for building a classifier for *like*/*not like* classes, it seems that I need **both** positive and negative examples. Should I really consider 'no action' as a negative one?

Answer (score 1):

It would be beneficial to check out PU learning (Positive Unknown). There are some techniques you can use to either treat these 'unknowns' as negatives that are very noisy, or to find the highest confident subset of unknowns to label as 'reliable negatives' to help classify the unknowns with more noise.

Answer (score 0):

The Rocchio equation for iteratively updating a query is
$$
\vec{q}_m = \alpha\vec{q}_0 + \beta\frac{1}{|D_r|}\sum_{\vec{d} \in D_r}\vec{d} - \gamma\frac{1}{|D_{nr}|}\sum_{\vec{d} \in D_{nr}}\vec{d}.
$$
So if you have no negative examples, just set the $\gamma$ parameter
to 0. That is the approach recommended on page 183 of the book An
Introduction to Information Retrieval.